# C#, .NET, String class

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone explain me , how it's possible.

```
 string str = "test";  
 str.Concat<>
```

I invoke Concat method, but String hasn't Concat Method with non-static keyword.

```
public static String Concat(object arg0);
public static String Concat(IEnumerable<String> values);
public static String Concat(params String[] values);
public static String Concat(params object[] args);
public static String Concat(String str0, String str1);
public static String Concat(object arg0, object arg1);
public static String Concat(String str0, String str1, String str2);
public static String Concat(object arg0, object arg1, object arg2);
public static String Concat(String str0, String str1, String str2, String str3);
public static String Concat(object arg0, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3);
public static String Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T> values);
```

this is the all Concat overloaded Methods that String class has.

If it's all static what method I've just called , there aren't any overloaded method for Concat with non-static keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have included `System.Linq` then you are seeing extension method `Concat<char>`. That is because `System.String` implements `IEnumerable<char>` interface and LINQ extension method is defined on that type.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided full code, but I suspect you're invoking [`Enumerable.Concat<char>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx), a generic [*extension method*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) provided by `System.Linq.Enumerable`, extending `IEnumerable<T>`. This is valid because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. For example:

```
IEnumerable<char> sequence = "abc".Concat("def");
foreach (var element in sequence)
{
   Console.WriteLine(element); // Prints a, then b, then c, then d, then e, then f
}
```

Note that `sequence` is *not* a string.